# How to structure PetaPOCO generated code in a 3 tier application?

Tags: architecture, orm, data-access-layer, petapoco

Earlier I always used to hand code the DAL and the Entities.  I would have a separate project called say MyEntities which would contain all the classes which map to database tables. The MyEntities assembly was then referenced by all the three tiers of the app, namely the DAL, BLL and the Presentation Layer.

Now I am trying out PetaPoco and used the T4 templates to auto-generate the Entity classes. This is awesome. But the problem is that these are generated in the DAL. Thus I have to provide reference to DAL dll in BLL and even Presentation Layer, which is incorrect.

What should be done in such cases?

Comment: Why do you say you need to reference the DAL in the Presentation Layer?

Comment: Because my DAL is a different class library project, separate from the Website project

Answer (score 2):

Look at [this sample PetaPoco project in GitHub](https://github.com/GarethElms/PetaPoco----A-simple-web-app) where the author make a good separation using repositories.

Comment: Here the repository is part of the same project. In my case, the repository is part of a separate class library, which is what creates my confusion.

Comment: the best thing i found after dayz